# jQuery Dropdown Menu Under IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

I have been fighting a stupid IE6/7 problem for awhile now, and hope someone with more experience than I can save me more wasted days.

I implemented a jQuery/CSS drop down menu that works fantastically under practically all browsers... except for our beloved IE7.  The following link points to a stripped-down test site that breaks down the problem into the minimal number of components.  You will find some main menu items that drop down into additional sub-items when hovered, but they don't drop down in IE7.  Please take a look at the following page, and help me understand where I have gone wrong... and what I can do to fix this in IE7.

Thanks in advance!

http://eatyourpet.info/menutest/index.php

Comment: Why are you even using jQuery for this? It can be done in CSS and still be compatible with IE 6?

Comment: Maybe our beloved IE7 make our salary! :D

Comment: Derp, I meant IE 7. IE 6 still requires a little bit of JS to add an .over state but jQuery is definitely not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going through your code (there's a lot of CSS styles, and it's probably going to be something really small) what you're trying to implement is a suckerfish dropdown ( http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/ ).

If you want to style it nicely like you've, it becomes a little more complicated, but this fiddle – http://jsfiddle.net/SZDkw/ – is a *super* basic implementation that works in IE 7, so take something that works and then build on that while checking in IE 7 as you go along.

Comment: I followed your advice and tried to build out a menu using the suckerfish method. Once complete I found that I experienced the same problem under IE7, but quickly realized that the menubar (which contains the menu) is actually preventing the menu from expanding below it.  http://eatyourpet.info/menutest/index2.php  The z-index property doesn't appear to make a difference with IE7, or I am implementing something wrong.  Further thoughts on breaking it outside it's menubar home?

Comment: Here's is an updated fiddle with my menubar:  http://jsfiddle.net/SZDkw/1/  It works fine except on IE7, how can I force the menu list to show outside the menubar under IE7?

Comment: The problem you're having with your menubar, is that you set the height to 17px, and that doesn't given the dropdown any room to expand into.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I don't have IE7 to test. Let me know if it was helpful:

```
$('#cssdropdown li.headlink').hover(function() { $(this).find('ul').toggle(); });
```